# tcl regex expression

Tags: regex, automation, tcl

```
regex {func(\(.*\))} "func(test)" a b
puts $a $b
```

I couldn't get test in b, and a prints func(test)

I was expecting a to be func and b to be test.
I'm a beginner to tcl, Any good resources for regex in tcl. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some inputs and expected outputs ..

Comment: Probably your best resource is [the Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) and [the Tcl man pages](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want variable "a" to hold "func" and variable "b" to hold "test", you have to capture all the text before the open parenthesis and all the text between the parentheses.
Here are 2 ways

1. using non-greedy quantifiers:

   ```
   regexp {^(.+?)\((.+?)\)} "func(test)" -> a b
   ```
2. using "negative" matching (with expanded regex for readability:

   ```
   regexp -expanded {
       ^ ( [^(]+ )    # from start of string, all non-open-parenthesis chars
       \(             # a literal open parenthesis
       ( [^)]+ )      # all non-close-parenthesis chars
       \)             # a literal close parenthesis
   }  "func(test)" -> a b
   ```

`->` is an odd-looking but valid Tcl variable that holds all the text that the regex matched. In both examples:

```
puts "$a => $b"    ;# func => test
```

Answer (score 1):

To match the parentheses literally, you have to escape them.  An unescaped parentheses is a regular expression grouping function.

```
regexp {func\((.*)\)} "func(test)" a b
```

Reference: [re_syntax](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: OP has escaped parentheses, just there is a formatting issue.